# Windows app to hold multiple items in clipboard

Tags: windows, gratis, windows-7, clipboard

I am looking for a simple [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) app that will extend the [clipboard](/questions/tagged/clipboard) to hold multiple items.

I don't need much, and would like to keep it simple.  Just something that will extend the clipboard to hold 2 or more items.  I do not want it to write the clipboard contents to non-volatile storage (e.g. hard drive) each time something is copied to the clipboard.

The app shouldn't affect normal operation of the clipboard (using it to copy-paste a single item).

I have a strong preference for [portable](/questions/tagged/portable) software, or at least something without and installer.

Must be compatible with [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7).

Comment: [quick multi-copy](http://goodlucksoft.com/quick-multi-copy.php) is the best tool I used.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/):

- gratis
- works on Microsoft Windows 7
- extend the clipboard to hold 2 or more items
- unsure how often it flushes the keyboard history to the hard drive, but it's pretty much lag free.
- there is a portable version.

[image]

No idea how people can use a computer without some clipboard manager.

Comment: Wow, thanks Franck.  I've never heard of Ditto.  Looks quite interesting.  Definitely overkill for what I need, but as you mentioned, it has a portable version and it's gratis, so definitely worth a try.  Plus it's open source.  Thanks again for the recommendation!

Comment: You beat me to it! I will second this wholeheartedly. I have been using Ditto for a few years now. Every few months I look for soemthing better, just in case and don't find anything. In fact, I don't know why I look, since Ditto does everything I could want.

Answer (score 5):

I'm using **[ArsClip](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=734)** for this:

[image]
<sup>*ArsClip* configuration and Clipboard windows (source: [PortableFreeware](http://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=734); click image for larger variant)</sup>

- Supports Windows XP to Windows 10 (which of course includes Windows 7)
- Extends the clipboard to hold more than 2 items (see right window in above screenshot)
- Is available in a portable version
- Is Freeware
- Is pretty much configurable
- Doesn't affect normal operation of the clipboard (items are [stacked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29), so last-in first-out; iow: it keeps a history for you to be accessed on demand only)

I'm using *ArsClip* for years. It's very reliable, stable, fast. Highly recommended :)

Comment: Thanks Izzy!  I've heard of ArsClip, but I forgot about it until your answer above.  I like how you mentioned that it doesn't affect normal operation of the clipboard.  That's nice, because keyboarding habits take time to change.

Comment: I'll upvote this too. I used it when the company gave me a 32-bit Windows Xp machine (standard for 20k+ employees - don't ask), as I couldn't fiind a 32 bitr version of Ditto. It is acceptable, streets ahead of the standard clipboard. But its featured cannot match those of Ditto.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [**Clipjump**](http://clipjump.sourceforge.net/).

- No extra shortcuts other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.
- Supports scripting, so you can add filters like trimming, change case etc.
- Fast, lightweight and portable.

Comment: Thanks lobo.  I didn't initially desire extra features, but the ability to write a script to trim whitespace is quite compelling.  Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 1):

I am using since many years the tool **[CLCL](http://www.nakka.com/soft/clcl/index_eng.html)**:

> - All clipboard formats are supported.
> - Template can be registered.
> - Pop-up menu is displayed by "Alt+C."
> - Menu can be customized.
> - Item is paste automatically.
> - Picture is displayed on a menu.
> - Tool tip is displayed on a menu.
> - The format to leave and the format to save can be set up.
> - The ignored window can be set up.
> - The paste key for every window can be set up.
> - Function is extensible with plug-in.
> - Unicode
> - Freeware

Supports Windows NT 4.0, 2000, XP, Vista, 7, 8, 8.1, 10. Source code available.

(Started with it because of a reference in [*The Productive Programmer* by Neal Ford](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002L4EXCY).)

Comment: Thanks sevenforce!  It looks interesting.  Does it have a portable version?

Comment: Yes, it has a portable version. You just have to unpack the zip file version from the link.

Answer (score 1):

For 10 years i was using different clipboard managers. Now time has come and I've made my own clipboard manager - Clip Angel (freeware) for Windows https://sourceforge.net/projects/clip-angel/?source=navbar . It was inspired by AceText and ClipDiary (my favourites).

Comment: Thanks! That's wonderful!  Is it portable?  Does it affect normal operation of the clipboard (using it to copy-paste a single item)?

Comment: Clip Angel has portable mode (ClipAngelPortable.bat). It always puts selected clip into clipboard to paste it. But I can make an option to restore original content of clipboard after paste if you need it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll play with it a little and see how it goes.  I'm super busy right now, so it might be a while...

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) for many years now. It remembers the last N items, and even has a way to create 'sticky' items that always appear in the menu. There's been no update since 2008, but the source is there if you really want to take it forward yourself. Downside is that it's not portable (it comes as an installer).